# Possible to use Qt Open Source integrated in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, qt

I'm currently having issues installing Qt (Open Source Edition) such that I can use it in integrated into Visual Studio 2010.  I realize that the 2008 edition will have deployment issues, and so I installed it from the source, only to be missing qtmaind.lib.

Anyways, I was looking around for a solution to this, and I came upon this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/install-win.html, which states:

> Open Source Versions of Qt is not officially supported for use with
>   any version of Visual Studio. Integration with Visual Studio is
>   available as part of the Qt Commercial Edition.

Anyways, I thought maybe this was the reason I was having problems, and so I wanted to ask the following question:

**Is it possible to integrate Open Source Qt into Visual Studio?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. I use Qt 4.7 integrated with Visual Studio 2005.

I configured Qt this way:

> configure -debug-and-release -opensource -shared -ltcg
>   -no-accessibility -no-qt3support

Once Qt was built (via nmake), I also installed the Qt [Visual Studio Add-in](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/visual-studio-add-in).